# Converting from Polar to Cartesian Equation

Tags: calculus

Consider the curve $r = 2\cos(\theta)$. How does one convert this to Cartesian coordinates? I know for a fact that
$$x^2 + y^2 = 4\cos^{2}(\theta)$$
and 
$$\begin{align}
&x = r\cos(\theta) = 2\cos^{2}(\theta)\\
&y= r\sin(\theta) = 2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Staring at this hasn't led to anything that sticks out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $x=2\cos^2 \theta \implies x-1=2\cos^2 \theta -1=\cos 2\theta$

Squaring, $\cos^2 2\theta= (x-1)^2$

Also, $y=2 \cos \theta \sin \theta=\sin 2\theta$

We then just have to exploit the Pythagorean identity: $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta=1$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply your equation by $r$. Complete the square.

Comment: This gives $r^2=2r\cos \theta$ aka $x^2+y^2=2x$. Etc.